# overflow encountered in numpy.rate

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
a = np.rate(240,100,-50,70000)
```

I get the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  t1 = (r+1)**n
```

while output is:

```
nan
```

If I get this right: the `r` coefficient gets too big and the whole formula stocks. But is there at least a way to figure it out if the output has a negative or positive value? Or is there any rule of thumb for setting a combination of parameters you could avoid error?

Answer (score 0):

```
np.rate(num_of_payments,month_payment,loan_amount,num_iteration_for_solutions)
condition for solution
|num_of_payments*month_payment|>loan_amount

month_payment should be negative (money change in your account)

suppose you loan 1000000$
pay 6000$
for 200 month
np.rate(200,-6000,1000000,0)
0.0018739577886206491
``
```

Comment: Thank you, could you explain this a bit more? I would appreciate it.

Comment: @filtertips No problem. , edited the answer, see if its more clear now

Comment: Yes, your case makes sense, we could also do: np.rate(200,6000,-1000000), and would get same result. However if you try my parameters, the result will be Nan. And I am trying to figure how to overcome Nan